# How to search specific documents by excluding some fields in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm a begginer in node.js and mongodb and please do excuse me if my question is foolish.Basically what I'm trying to do is search fields by their fullname which is working fine but if I wanna search for all fullnames except one fullname then how to do it.

Code:

```
 //This code is working fine
 var string = data.search.replace(/[\/\\#@+()$~%'":*?<>{}]/g, '')
            var regex = new RegExp(["^", string].join(""), "i");

        db.collection("user_information").find({fullname:regex },{_id:0}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if(err) throw err;
              console.log(result);

            socket.emit("search",result)

            db.close();

        });
```

**But this code is giving error**

```
   db.collection("user_information").find({fullname:regex }, 
   {fullname:{$ne:"david jones"}}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if(err) throw err;
              console.log(result);

            socket.emit("search",result)

            db.close();

        });//I'm trying to exclude the name by "$ne"
```

**This is giving []**

```
db.collection("user_information").find({fullname:{regex,$ne:"srinivas.nahak"}}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if(err) throw err;
              console.log(result);

            socket.emit("search",result)

            db.close();

        });
```

Error:

```
MongoError: Unsupported projection option: fullname: { $ne: "srinivas.nahak" }
at Function.MongoError.create (C:\Users\Srinu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:31:11)
at queryCallback (C:\Users\Srinu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:212:36)
at C:\Users\Srinu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:469:18
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need another semicolon in your argument to find. E.g.

> { fullname : { $ne : "david jones" } }

See official docs for $ne here

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/

Though on a second reading of the official docs it is possible that $ne is not a valid operator within a projection - you might have to include this in the actual query.

I believe the second argument to find allows you to specify the fields that should be returned from your query I.e.

> { field1: 1, field2: 0 }

This would ensure field1 is returned but exclude field2.

It looks like the values you can pass in a projection can be 1, true, 0, false, $, $elemMatch, $slice, $meta

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/#

You may be able to build your desired query using $and - checkout documentation here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/

Comment: Sir thanks for your attention but it was a typing mistake